# Calling the method from the subclass (polymorphism)

Tags: java, polymorphism, extends

I have abstract class:

```
public abstract class Owoc {

public Owoc(){};

private String name;
private double weight;

public String getName(){
    return name;
}
public void setName(String newName){
    this.name = newName;
}
...
```

And the subclass Truskawka:

```
public class Truskawka extends Owoc {

public Truskawka(){
    setName("truskawka");
    setWeight(1);
}

public void growTruskawka() {
    System.out.println(getName() + " is growing");
}
```

}

How to call method growTruskawka() in main class when I iterate through all the Owocs in below case:

```
owoc = owocFactory.makeOwoc(typeOfOwoc);
owoc.growTruskawka();
```

I tried to cast but it does not work: The java tells "Required truskawka, Found Owoc"

```
(Truskawka) owoc = owocFactory.makeOwoc(typeOfOwoc);
```

Comment: No clear description of the problem, no relevant code...

Comment: it does not work, means? runtime error/compilation error? Also, please put some code which is relevant to pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use polymorphism put the method `grow` in the base class (`Owoc`) and override it in the subclasses (like `Truskawka`).

For example, in `Owoc`:

```
public void grow() {
    System.out.println("grow() from Owoc");
}
```

In `Truskawka`:

```
@Override
public void grow() {
    System.out.println(getName() + " is growing");
}
```

Then if you have an instance of `Truskawka`, calling `grow` will execute its specific method:

```
Owoc owoc = new Truskawka();
owoc.grow();   // this will print "truskawka is growing"
```